# on-device symbolication of crash logs for ios apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

is it possible to symbolize a crash log on device ? if yes is there is any documentation of xcode which guides to do that ? thanks.

Actually the purpose is i am not keeping track of my dsyms and every time i get a crash i have to do a gamble to find out the dsym and then later start my analysis on the crash.

what i tried to fix this was going for 3rd party github projects which does the same thing in may additional features like email, server side component to receive logs and things like that. but they seems to be too much for my purpose when what all i require was to just add symbols so that crash logs are meaningful

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't tracking your dsym files there is no way to symbolicate crash logs. The best you can do is include logging statements of your own throughout your code which indicate what method is being called (you could probably use method/class swizzling to inject this behavior across all your types, but it still wouldn't be as useful as real symbolicated crash logs). Just start checking the dsyms into source control, tagged with your version number.

Comment: This is not true. Many crash reporting libraries symbolicate on-device (or did, historically).